# Add class to element this element is child of?

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass, removeclass

I'm trying to add a class "active" to the li that was clicked on, however in my script, I'm retrieving the a that was clicked on since I'd like to retrieve the href of "". What's the script to do that?

```
<ul class = "tab-links">
        <!-- Each tab is Anchored to its Contents -->
        <li class = "active"><a href ="#panel1">Panel 1</a></li>
        <li><a href ="#panel2">Panel 2</a></li>
        <li><a href ="#panel3">Panel 3</a></li>
        <li><a href ="#panel4">Panel 4</a></li>
</ul>



 <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function () 
  {

    //Listen for tab-links clicks
    $('.tab-panels .tab-links a ').on('click', function (e)
        {   
            //Remove current active panelToShow
            $('.tab-panels .tab-links li.active').removeClass('active');

            //Make panelToShow link active
            //??How do I addClass active to the li that was clicked on, when "this" refers to an "a" element?  
            //????$(this).addClass('active');
  ... })
   } 
 </script> ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `parent`

```
$(this).parent("li").addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
$(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
```

This will add the class `active` to the nearest parent of the link which is a `li`